TypeError: C function scipy.linalg._cythonized_array_utils.__pyx_fuse_0swap_c_and_f_layout has wrong signature
For the simple
import sklearn
I am getting the following error, and I have no idea how to fix it.
{
    "name": "TypeError",
    "message": "C function scipy.linalg._cythonized_array_utils.__pyx_fuse_0swap_c_and_f_layout has wrong signature (expected void (float *, float *, int, int, int), got void (float *, float *, int, int))",
    "stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/6g/kczfnvwx61n0pyjkk9swlgrm0000gn/T/ipykernel_44026/1232488958.py in <module>
----> 1 import sklearn
      2 print(sklearn.__version__)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py in <module>
     82         _distributor_init,  # noqa: F401
     83     )
---> 84     from .base import clone
     85     from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
     86 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in <module>
     17 from ._config import config_context, get_config
     18 from .exceptions import InconsistentVersionWarning
---> 19 from .utils._estimator_html_repr import _HTMLDocumentationLinkMixin, estimator_html_repr
     20 from .utils._metadata_requests import _MetadataRequester, _routing_enabled
     21 from .utils._param_validation import validate_parameter_constraints

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py in <module>
      9 from . import _joblib, metadata_routing
     10 from ._bunch import Bunch
---> 11 from ._chunking import gen_batches, gen_even_slices
     12 from ._estimator_html_repr import estimator_html_repr
     13 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_chunking.py in <module>
      6 
      7 from .._config import get_config
----> 8 from ._param_validation import Interval, validate_params
      9 
     10 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_param_validation.py in <module>
      9 
     10 import numpy as np
---> 11 from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix, issparse
     12 
     13 from .._config import config_context, get_config

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/sparse/__init__.py in <module>
    306 
    307 # For backward compatibility with v0.19.
--> 308 from . import csgraph
    309 
    310 # Deprecated namespaces, to be removed in v2.0.0

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/sparse/csgraph/__init__.py in <module>
    183            'NegativeCycleError']
    184 
--> 185 from ._laplacian import laplacian
    186 from ._shortest_path import (
    187     shortest_path, floyd_warshall, dijkstra, bellman_ford, johnson,

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/sparse/csgraph/_laplacian.py in <module>
      5 import numpy as np
      6 from scipy.sparse import issparse
----> 7 from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator
      8 from scipy.sparse._sputils import convert_pydata_sparse_to_scipy, is_pydata_spmatrix
      9 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/__init__.py in <module>
    127 \"\"\"
    128 
--> 129 from ._isolve import *
    130 from ._dsolve import *
    131 from ._interface import *

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/_isolve/__init__.py in <module>
      4 from .iterative import *
      5 from .minres import minres
----> 6 from .lgmres import lgmres
      7 from .lsqr import lsqr
      8 from .lsmr import lsmr

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/_isolve/lgmres.py in <module>
      4 import numpy as np
      5 from numpy.linalg import LinAlgError
----> 6 from scipy.linalg import get_blas_funcs
      7 from .iterative import _get_atol_rtol
      8 from .utils import make_system

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/linalg/__init__.py in <module>
    213 from ._decomp_schur import *
    214 from ._decomp_polar import *
--> 215 from ._matfuncs import *
    216 from .blas import *
    217 from .lapack import *

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/linalg/_matfuncs.py in <module>
     16 from ._expm_frechet import expm_frechet, expm_cond
     17 from ._matfuncs_sqrtm import sqrtm
---> 18 from ._matfuncs_expm import pick_pade_structure, pade_UV_calc
     19 
     20 # deprecated imports to be removed in SciPy 1.13.0

_matfuncs_expm.pyx in init scipy.linalg._matfuncs_expm()

TypeError: C function scipy.linalg._cythonized_array_utils.__pyx_fuse_0swap_c_and_f_layout has wrong signature (expected void (float *, float *, int, int, int), got void (float *, float *, int, int))"
}

I tried uninstalling and installing sklearn, numpy, and scipy

Can you provide versions for scipy and sklearn? Can you tell us whether you used pip or conda to install them? Can you provide operating system information?
